# Retrieve the WIQL of a saved query created in TFS

Tags: tfs, wiql

I have created a query in TFS interactively using the web interface. Now I want to get the WIQL that it is using.

The only way I know how is to call [the RESTful api](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries), and pass $expand=wiql. Is there an easier way? Ideally from the interactive web interface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Chrome's "Developer Tools" (under "More Tools") click the Network tab and run the TFS query.  You'll see the query item in the list of items.  Click on the query item and you'll see the WIQL code in the view pane.

Example:
[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I've been looking for something like this for months!

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't seem like you can do it in the Web Access. You can however do it in Visual Studio (if you have it).

Open the Query and then Edit it, now if you do **File**, **Save as...** you can then save the query as a `.wiq` XML file, that will include the WIQL:

[image: save as dialog]

Example content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WorkItemQuery Version="1">
    <TeamFoundationServer>https://----.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection</TeamFoundationServer>
    <TeamProject>Test Agile</TeamProject>
    <Wiql>SELECT [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.State], 
    [Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints], [System.IterationPath], [System.Tags] 
    FROM WorkItemLinks 
    WHERE Source.[System.WorkItemType] in group 'Microsoft.RequirementCategory' 
</WorkItemQuery>
```

Comment: Thanks. Not ideal, since many of our team does not have VS installed. But good to know!

Comment: Team Explorer Everywhere might offer the same functionality if you have eclipse users..