# VSTS Iterate over all WorkItems in an Epic

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-process-template, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-rest-api

I am building a VSTS dashboard widget where I would like to iterate over all **Features** in a particular **Epic**, and then for each **Feature** gather data about all the **WorkItems** to create a status report.

I know I can use [`getWorkItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_1?view=vsts#getworkitem()) and [`getWorkItems()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_1?view=vsts#getworkitems()), but that is if I already know the WorkItem IDs. I want to loop through all the features and then all the WorkItems and see if they are completed, without knowing their particular ids.

Comment: you should start from a given Epic (you need to know its id), and then iterate over all children Features.

Comment: Yes but what function do I use to retrieve the epic in the first place? I only see getWorkItems(). There is no: getFeatures() or getFeature() or even getEpic() for that matter. I am new to VSTS in general so maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Getworkitem() can fetch any kind of workitem, and each workitem has a type.

Comment: @user8463863 Have you tried by WIQL as jessehouwing mentions?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I will give it a try, however I am unsure what to pass as parameters to the function? From what I understand I need to instantiate a client and then just call the static method with some parameters. The issue is I don't know what wiql is. Is it the "id" of an epic? Is it the name of the category, so just "epic". The name of the epic. Or is it the query id, in which case do I have to create a new query in the code?

Comment: @jessehouwing Do I need to require the "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient" client? My biggest issue is know "how" to use the clients. For example, what are the functions for the variable: TFS_Wit_WebApi? In some examples, I see it has a getClient() method, and that has a .getQuery() method, but how would I know that without a simple tutorial. Isn't there any documentation on all of this. I will continue experimenting, thanks!

Comment: @LucaCappa By default getWorkItem(epicID) will not return a list of features. How exactly do I iterate over all the children Features then?

Comment: @user8463863 Use the Link property in the returned workitem, It is a LinkCollection. On this collection, iterate over the links, for each of them you can get the link type and the linked work item. You should collect all the linked workitem of type Feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VSTS work item tracking system is very extensible, therefore there aren't any "fixed" methods that will return you specific work item types. Even though features in VSTS rely on one or more levels of work items being present, their name, the fields and other aspects of these work items are highly configurable.

To query the available work item levels (called Categories in VSTS), [you can use the Categories/List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/). This will allow you to find hierarchy as it's configured in VSTS and which work item types are available at each level.

[You can use the ProcessConfiguration/Get API to list the relationship between the different backlog levels.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/work/processconfiguration/get) Which is a parent of which and what type of backlog it represents. Is it a Task (lowest level), Requirement (Story, PBI level, planning level), or a Portfolio (Epic, Feature etc) level backlog.

With this information, [you can either use the Backlig/GetBacklogWorkItems API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/work/backlogs/get%20backlog%20level%20work%20items) to fetch all the work items on a specific backlog or you can [construct a WIQL (Work Item Query Language) query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/wiql-syntax?view=vsts) to retrieve all work items that match that specific query. You can either [export the WIQL from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38338535/736079) or [use an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor).

Depending on what you need with each work item you can either query directly for the required fields, or just query the work item ID's and fetch the work item details individually using the workitem/getWorkItems(id) API.

There is pretty extensive documentation available on each of these API's and on the required VSTS services you can use from your extension. going deep to explain each of the services goes too far for this answer. I suggest you start experimenting from here and ask new questions as they arise. You now have far more information to work with and it will be easier to ask targetted questions from there.

Comment: I would like to get a list of all the Feature IDs, given an Epic ID. I have read about getWorkItems()  and even tried using the 4th parameter to include the fields but I cannot seem to find a way to get a list of Feature IDs that I will then iterate over to get details about their individual PBIs. Any suggestions? Do I have to use WIQL in this case? The WIQL documentation is arcane and I don't know how to construct it with **code**.

Comment: Yes WIQL... there is a Linq provider for WIQL https://github.com/kevinpohlmeier/WiqLinq