# Query for workitems which are resolved duplicate to another workitem which itself is resolved fixed

Tags: c#, azure-devops, tfs, tfs-workitem, wiql

I'd like to query for all WorkItems which:

- Resolved as a duplicate
- Are created by a specific user
- Resolved within a specific date
- Pointing to another workitem resolved as fixed

This is what I've tried:

```
string itemsMarkedDuplicateParentFixed = "Select [Target].[ID] From WorkItemLinks Where " +
                        "[Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' And " +
                        "[Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Bug' And " +
                        "[Source].[System.State]='Resolved' And " +
                        "[Source].[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason]='Duplicate' And " +
                        "[Target].[System.State]='Resolved' And " +
                        "[Target].[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedReason]='Fixed' And " +
                        "[Source].[System.CreatedBy] = 'TomSelleck' And " +
                        $"[Target].[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate]>='{resolvedDateFrom}' And" +
                        $"[Target].[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedDate]<='{resolvedDateTo}'";

IEnumerable <WorkItem> appCompatBugsMarkedFixed = await vsoService.GetWorkItems(new Wiql() {
    Query = appCompatBugsMarkedDuplicateParentFixed
});

...

public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkItem>> GetWorkItems(Wiql wiqlQuery)
{
    using (var workClient = await GetClient())
    {
        var queryResults = await workClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiqlQuery);
        return await workClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(queryResults.WorkItemRelations.Select(x => x.Target.Id), expand: WorkItemExpand.All);
    }
}
```

I'm hitting this error:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: 'Not Found'

[image]

I'm struggling to find any C# examples which achieve what I want.

Comment: mmmm seems the query string you're sending to GetWorkItems isn't the same we can see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try your query through Web or Visual Studio designer? You can create a query, test it and then export it on VS ([Retrieve the WIQL of a saved query created in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335488/retrieve-the-wiql-of-a-saved-query-created-in-tfs)) or [Wiql Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor). The example similar to your query:

Query in the designer:

[image]

Query wiql:

[image]

Comment: Using the editor is a much better way to quickly test and prototype before adding to code. Thanks